# I'm getting a weird warning 'React hook useEffect has a missing dependency'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm getting the following warning in React

> 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'bakerys'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setFlatbakery' needs the current value of 'bakerys'. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)'

**bakerys** and **Flatbakery** are react state variables.

```
export default function App() {
  const [bakerys, setBakerys] = useState([]);
  const [flatbakery, setFlatbakery] = useState({ 
    header: [],
    data: []
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    // fectchData is function to fecth data from API
    fetchData().then((randomData) => {
      setBakerys(randomData);
      setFlatbakery(extractData(bakerys)) // extractData is a function.
    });
  }, []);
return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Comment: I think that warning is from ESLint,  just put to ignore intentionally empty deps:
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting two state variables at the same time. What is more, one update depends on the other. Don't do that. Simply separate the updates into two separate effects:

```
export default function App() {
  const [bakeries, setBakeries] = useState([]);
  const [flatbakery, setFlatbakery] = useState({ 
    header: [],
    data: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((randomData) =>
      setBakeries(randomData);
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFlatbakery(extractData(bakeries));
  }, [bakeries]);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```